# psql faild to restor file from network drive

Tags: postgresql, windows, psql

i have a dump file on drive z (network drive)
im opening the psql from PgAdmin4
this is the command that im writeing:

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -f Z:\DB_BU\md_20220729.sql
```

and this is the error that im getting:

```
Invalid command \DB_BU. Try \? for help.
```

when im doing this:

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -f i\ Z:\DB_BU\md_20220729.sql
```

> Invalid command \DB_BU. Try ? for help.

and when im doing this:

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -f "Z:\DB_BU\md_20220729.sql"
```

im not getting any error but also its not restoring the file. how can i restor the file?

Comment: Did you try `-f "Z:/DB_BU/md_20220729.sql"`?

Comment: i tryed it now, but with no effect

Comment: The try `cd /d Z:\DB_BU` then run `psql` from within that directory using `-f md_20220729.sql`

Comment: [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is a standalone program, not an SQL command you can run in PGAdmin. You need to run it outside PGADmin in cmd/bash/PowerShell that sees it, or use SQL [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) from within PGAdmin if the file is in one of the supported formats and the network location visible and accessible by the database. From psql you could use `\copy` pointing at a local path visible by your psql client.

Comment: " opening the psql from PgAdmin4 "  I don't think there is such a thing as that.  psql is one thing PgAdmin4 is something else.

Comment: in pgadmin 4 ther is an option to open psql tool

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `psql` from within `psql` or PGAdmin. Since
[`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is a standalone program, not an SQL command you can run in PGAdmin SQL window or `psql`'s own, internal [*meta-command*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) you're getting the error

```
Invalid command \DB_BU. Try \? for help
```

indicating that there was an attempt to interpret your entire command as a SQL query or an internal command and that this attempt failed.

You can [open "psql tool" from within PGAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/psql_tool.html) but your command won't work there either because it's trying to call `psql` itself, with some command-line options, which you cannot do when you're already inside an interactive `psql` session. The command

```bash
psql -U postgres -d postgres -f Z:\DB_BU\md_20220729.sql
```

can be used **outside** `psql` and PGAdmin, in your terminal, like [zsh on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/apdb66b5242-0d18-49fc-9c47-a2498b7c91d5/2.13/mac/13.0), [sh/bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) on Linux, cmd or PowerShell on Windows, where `psql` is installed and visible, along with your network path.

If you're able to open the [`psql` tool window in PGAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/psql_tool.html), you can instead try and use an [internal psql `\i`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#:%7E:text=Reads%20input%20from%20the%20file%20filename%20and%20executes%20it%20as%20though%20it%20had%20been%20typed%20on%20the%20keyboard.:%7E:text=%5Ci%20or%20%5Cinclude%20filename) [*meta-command*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) which is basically the same thing as the [`-f`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS:%7E:text=%2Df%20filename%0A%2D%2Dfile,everything%20by%20hand.) command-line option, but meant for use inside the `psql` session:

```sql
\i "Z:\DB_BU\md_20220729.sql"
```